# Drupal 6 CCK Field Not Showing

Tags: drupal

In Drupal 6, I added a custom field to a custom content type.

The name is: "field_publishedin"

I then added data into that field for some sample articles.

In the view for it, I added that field as well.

On the page that renders it I added the code to show the field as well:

```
<div class="press-content">
<div class="family-news">
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
<div class="news">
    <div class="data">Posted on <a href="<?php print url('news/'.$row['created_1']) ?>">           <?php print $row['created'] ?></a> </div><!--DATA-->
    <h4><?php print $row['title'] ?><span><?php print $row['field_publishedin_value']; ?></span></h4>
</div><!--NEWS-->
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>
```

So the code I added is `<span><?php print $row['field_publishedin_value']; ?></span>` since according to the view when using in a template you are suppose to add "_value".

However, I clicked rescan templates, emptied the drupal cache but that new code still does not render on the page.

When I add this to the page: `<?php print '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($rows, 1)) . '</pre>'; ?>` and it outputs the possible array values it does not show, "field_publishedin_value" so it seems like the template doesnt know that field exists even though its in the view. Help?

Answer (score 0):

install the devel module, and in to *.tpl.php, place:

```
<?php
dpm($fields); // if views 
// or dpm($node); if it's a node or page.tpl.php
// of if you don't know, dpm(get_defined_vars());
?>
```

Also, if this is views, the template you should be using is the views-view-fields.tpl.php. Note the PLURAL fields.

Joe

Comment: Its in the following template: views-view-table--news.tpl.php Another coder got it working but can't figure out how they did it even looking through all their code and backend. But haven't heard back from them yet on how they did it so trying to figure on my own in the mean time.

Comment: oh and adding that code only outputs the same thing as the code I have in my question above: <?php print '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($rows, 1)) . '</pre>'; ?> which as noted does not show the field_published_in in the available array, which means the problem is somewhere hire up but cant figure out what.

Comment: if the var isn't in the $fields array, it's not being sent to the template by views. You don't have 'exclude from display' checked in the views ui for that field do you?